DateTimeZone.UTC for a DatePicker Control is returning misleading/wring date inside Power Apps canvas application
I have a Form inside Power Apps canvas >> and i have a date field named Start >> and i set the DateTimeZone to be DateTimeZone.UTC , as follow:-

now currently i have this regional setting  (UTC+3) for a user account:-

so now when i select 15/09/2024 inside the DatePicker (as shown in the first picture)>> i would assume that the generated datetime will be 14/09/2024 21:00:00 since i am 3 hour in advance to UTC, but the datetime will be 14/09/2024 03:00:00 ,as follow:-

so how i can fix this wrong date? at the end i need to send this date to power automate in UTC format/time-zone? how i can fix this? so if i select 15/09/2024 inside the calendar i want to get 14/09/2024 21:00:00 which is the UTC of the UTC+3 (my regional time zone)
